# I ran a loop containing a ggplot function, but it nothing appears

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, statistics, bioinformatics

I ran a loop containing a ggplot function, but no object nor plot is produced. The problem is that no Error signs appear on the console or in the markdown either.
Legend (for the code):

- anova_total: table containing anova p-values for all the proteins in table_for_statistics
- table_for_statistics: pivoted table containing all the data that I need (but no anova results).

From anova_total, I filtered all the proteins with a certain p-value that I need for all the 3 variables, and I obtained the ID of those proteins (which are the rownames in anova_total) because I don't need the anova results themselves for the plot I have to make. I only need to know the IDs of the proteins I have to plot; the features I need to plot are contained in table_for_statistics.

Here is my code:

```
for (k in colnames(anova_total)){
imp.prot.cat <- table_for_statistics[table_for_statistics$protein %in% sig.total$sig.total,]

print(ggplot(table_for_statistics[table_for_statistics$protein %in% imp.prot.cat,], aes(x= table_for_statistics[table_for_statistics$protein %in% imp.prot.cat, k], y= measurement))+
  geom_beeswarm(aes(col= iss_group), shape=21, size=2,cex = 0.5)+
  facet_wrap(~protein, scale ="free_y")+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") + 
  stat_compare_means(method = "t.test"))

 }
```

You can see the datasets in the loop by clicking the following link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwFsS.png

Thank you!

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: FYI, you subset the data into `imp.prot.cat` precisely the same way each time in the loop; if this is large-ish data then this is seriously inefficient. I recommend you move that assignment outside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

In this link you have a really good explanation of how ggplot works with loops.

https://statisticsglobe.com/print-ggplot2-plot-within-for-loop-in-r

We need to wrap the print function around the R code creating the plot.
Using the next function with the number of seconds within will show you the plots with the time delay specified.

```
Sys.sleep(2)
```

In your case:

```
for (k in seq_along(anova_total)){
imp.prot.cat <- table_for_statistics[table_for_statistics$protein %in% sig.total$sig.total,]

print(ggplot(table_for_statistics[table_for_statistics$protein %in% imp.prot.cat,], aes(x= table_for_statistics[table_for_statistics$protein %in% imp.prot.cat, k], y= measurement))+
  geom_beeswarm(aes(col= iss_group), shape=21, size=2,cex = 0.5)+
  facet_wrap(~protein, scale ="free_y")+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") + 
  stat_compare_means(method = "t.test"))
Sys.sleep(2)
 }
```

By using colnames you are retrieving or setting the names of the columns, try to use seq_along() to move from k trough all your dataframe  until the end.
Even though you do not have errors you can check the warnings by calling warnings().

Comment: This answer is so thorough and clear, thank you so much. I will try and let you know!

Comment: @Beth I hope it finally worked fine. If it was useful I will appreaciate if you can accept it as good answer :)